# Is it possible move JavaFX nodes between Parents in newer versions of JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

JavaFX 19,

Apparently we used to be able to move a javafx node to a new parent using parent.getChildren().add(node). However, getChildren is now protected making it inaccessible. I also tried changing its accessibility using trySetAccessible(), but this returns false indicating the method is not capable of being set to accessible. What I'm wondering is how am I supposed to move nodes from one parent to another now that getChildren is no longer available?

For example, if I have a Kotlin method:

```
fun moveNode( parent: Parent, child: Node) {
    //First remove child from current parent
    child.parent.getChildren().remove(child)
    //Then add child to new parent
    parent.getChildren().add(child)
```

This seems like such a useful action for turning traditional applications into dynamic programs, I'm also curious why JavaFX no longer allows it. Thanks for all the help!

Comment: *”Apparently we used to be able to move a javafx node to a new parent using parent.getChildren().add(node).”* No. This statement is false. This was never allowed outside of a `Parent` subclass.

Comment: @James_D so are you saying that I should make my controller inherit from Parent or one of its subclasses, like Pane?

Comment: If you want to access the children publicly use a Group or Pane (or a subclass of those), as it has always been.

Comment: All I am saying is that your question is predicated on a false premise, so it doesn’t really have any meaningful answer. And no, you should not make your controller a subclass of `Parent`, or any other class that is part of the view.

Answer (score 2):

You must have messed up something there. I can't see anything that has been changed here since JavaFX 8. Parent has a protectrd children property and a protected getChildren() method which you cannot directly access from some other class and Pane has a public getChildren() method which can be accessed directly from anywhere.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to pre-JavaFX 8, just wasn't sure what the number actually was. Thanks! I found examples like the one I gave in docs, although sorry I did not save the link. So I definitely did not 'mess up'. Now do you know anything about the question I'm asking?

Comment: @GavinRay As far as I can tell, the `Parent#getChildren()` method has _always_ been `protected`.  At least, the [JavaFX 2](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/Parent.html#getChildren()) Javadoc says it is. And even [this documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/javafx/javafx/1.3/docs/api/javafx.scene/javafx.scene.Parent.html#) allegedly for JavaFX 1.3 has it marked as "protected" (though I'm not sure about the particulars of JavaFX 1.x; pretty sure some significant changes occurred by JavaFX 2).

Comment: @GavinRay Ah, I didn't realize the attempt to use reflection (I see now you mentioned `trySetAccessible()`). Part of your problem is with the _Java Platform Module System_ (JPMS) then. Only `public` members can be reflectively accessed from packages which the module `exports`. A module must `opens` a package to access non-public members. You could work around this by specifying an appropriate `--add-opens` JVM argument at run-time, though you may want to consider if what you're trying to do (fight against the API) is worth it.

Answer (score -3):

I think I found an answer, but please somebody fact check me on this. Pane objects (which inherit from Parent and Node) replace the getChildren method with a public version. As far as I can tell, only Pane's have accessible children, and are intended to be used this way. So all I have to do is make sure I am ALWAYS moving nodes to a Pane, instead of Parent like in the example above.

Also looks like getChildren() was replaced with children property.

```
fun moveNode( parent: Pane, child: Node) {
    //First remove child from current parent
    child.parent.children.remove(child)
    //Then add child to new parent
    parent.children.add(child)
```

Update: According to AI, all these Parent objects have accessible getChildren methods...

```
Pane (and its subclasses: FlowPane, GridPane, HBox, StackPane, TilePane, VBox)

Group

CustomNode (and its subclasses)
```

Comment: "_Also looks like getChildren() was replaced with children property_" -- You're writing in Kotlin, and Kotlin automatically "translates" Java getters and setters so they can be accessed like Kotlin properties (Kotlin properties with backing fields are compiled down to getters and setters anyway, at least when targetting the JVM).

Comment: `child.parent.children.remove(child)` -- This should fail to compile, as `Node#getParent()` returns a `Parent`, which means the `#getChildren()` method is `protected` (regardless of the real type of the parent at run-time). You'd have to cast the returned object to `Pane` (or `Group`), which obviously has a chance of failing if the object is not an instance of the appropriate type.

Comment: I'm also not sure the explicit removal from the current parent is needed. I believe adding a node to another parent automatically causes it to be removed from its current parent, if it has one. Though if you get an exception when trying that, then obviously that's not true.